# Admob low money

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, banner

1. I have over 6.000 impressions ( banner and interstitial ) but I get low money for this impression? How can I optimize that?

   Here is a screenshot:

   [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3r70u74yetgsiic/Foto%2024.05.16%2C%2011%2056%2025.png?dl=0]
2. I can't see the AdMob banner during the game. But on the simulator ( xcode ios app ) I can see the banner.

I have updated the Google SDK.

I have asked the AdMob team but they're saying that everything is OK.

On itunesconnect I have selected that there are ads from AdMob.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even it is quite dependent on app itself, your RPM is very low. 0.1 - 0.2 euro is totally unacceptable.
Can you please try increasing refresh period to at least 90 seconds?. It will definitely help your revenue.
Also your revenue is dependent to your app's users demography. US gives very high RPM but Russia has much lower. You can try to increase your traffic from high RPM countries.

Comment: Ok thank you. I try it. I had changed it to 30 seconds because i had same result. I try it with 90 seconds

Comment: If this impression numbers are for 30 seconds refresh period, so they are a bit low.

Comment: I tried 90 seconds but now i have low impression. And i have still the second problem. I cant see the banner. I have tried it on 2 other devices but no banner. But on admob i get impressions for the banner

Comment: It is normal to have lower impression. Approximately 1/3 compared with 30 seconds. Butt your revenue will be much better with a bit patience. Kinda silly but do you have internet connection

Comment: Yes, internetconnection is there. On simulator and test device it works.

Answer (score 1):

heyho

1) You have a common stat for banner and interstitial both. Admob mostly pays on CPC, but also uses CPM, this means two things:
1.1 You need more users and traffic, to get more money on CPC/CPM basis. I'd advise to make the store page of the app more attractive. Make some nice looking HD screenshots. Video walkthrough is a good thing especially for a game. This can help with new users + you can google lots of useful tips.
1.2 CPC model relies on clicks of your users. So another crucial aspect is the right ad format and placement. It would be great to understand what kind of app you have. If it's a utility app -  banner ads might work, but native ads would look better + users perceive them much better, cause they're not so irritating. If you have a game - i'd advice rewarded video and interstitials. Anyway, you should know and understand your users better than anyone else.

2) Seems like it's a matter of sdk implementation. Make sure you initialize both ad types: banner and interstitial. If Admob support says everything is fine, maybe there's a bug on device or you should update the app on device.